# strange exception that i cant solve

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, curly-braces

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;

public class test {
    int y = (60 * 40);
    public static JLabel timer = new JLabel("");

    public test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("timer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(timer);
        frame.setSize(1000, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setForeground(Color.black);
        timer.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 100));
        timer.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() { //line 29
            public void run() {
                test2 it = new test2();
                Thread wasd = new Thread(it);
                new test();
                wasd.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For some strange reason, the compiler says there needs to be a try/catch block on line 29 but everytime i try.... it fails. The curly braces refuse to cooperate with me, and end up on parsing errors, because it skips whatever try blocks i put in there. I dunno a way outta this.

Comment: Start by properly indenting your code, then I wouldn't be surprised if you spot the problem right away.

Comment: Proper indentation will help. Also can you show the code that you tried already?

Comment: If you formatted your code like how I formatted it for you, maybe you'd have an idea on what on earth you're doing.

Comment: sigh, beginner's misfortune

Answer (score 0):

```
public test() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("timer");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(timer);
    frame.setSize(1000, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setForeground(Color.black);
    timer.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 100));
    timer.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                test it = new test();
                Thread wasd = new Thread();
                new test();
                wasd.start();
            }

        });
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: /** Please add avobe of the code */  public class test {
 int y = (60 * 40);
 public static JLabel timer = new JLabel("");